# Adding a DAO Recordset to Subroutine - vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am using vba in Access 2010, and I am just trying to pass in a DAO recordset into a subroutine.  I am doing this so I don't have to duplicate code (potentially hundreds of lines).  I believe this is very simple, but every time I try something it freezes the program and I am forced to restart Access and re-add my code. Below is all of the code I have tried:

```
Sub WriteToForms(rs as RecordSet) ' When I press enter, that is when it freezes

Sub WriteToForms(ByVal rs as RecordSet) ' When I press enter, that is when it freezes

Sub WriteToForms(ByRef rs as RecordSet) 'When I press enter, that is when it freezes
```

However, when I do this:

```
Sub WriteToForms (types as string)
```

It works. I have looked at multiple articles and the above code is what they suggested.

Comment: Try specifying which type of recordset - ADODB or DAO.

Comment: It would make more sense if you could show a bit more code, the above could not always be the reason for the freeze. Also make sure you reference the Recordset, use DAO or ADO

Comment: @PaulFrancis I don't know what other code I can show you.  The other code I have is irrelevant for I can't even create this subroutine to begin passing data in.

Comment: @Rory It is a DAO recordset, I have updated the question and the details.

Comment: I pass Recordsets to subroutines and it always works. I cannot see why else it should fail, have you tried adding DAO? Like `Sub WriteToForms(rs as DAO.RecordSet)`

Comment: I feel like a dolt.  that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing a recordset to a subroutine in Access you must specify what type of recordset it is.  For example:

```
Sub WriteToForms(rs as recordset)
```

Should actually be:

```
Sub WriteToForms(rs as Dao.RecordSet) 'If you are dealing with a DAO recordset.
```

OR

```
Sub WriteToForms(rs as ADODB.RecordSet) 'If you are dealing with a ADO recordset.
```

Failure to specify the type of recordset will cause the program to freeze and you will need to restart Access/Excel.